# Angular material progress bar not working

Tags: angular-material

I'm to add an angular material spinner, but can't even have the basic one works on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvd2cq). I've added everything the way the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/examples) suggest, but I'm still getting nowhere.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing to define a theme in `styles.css`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbet9b?file=src/styles.css

Or you can also define the stroke color in `styles.css`:

```
.mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle {
    stroke: red;
}
```

I would suggest to pre-define a theme and then override in `styles.css` so in case you forget to define maybe a color at least the default color appears.